# Doubts about Computations for Splines (B-splines) in The Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: splines

On page 186, the augmented knot $τ$ is used and it says that $τ$ takes all equal values and is equal to $ξ_0$ and $ξ_{K+1}$. Next, the definition of the basis function $B_{i,m}$ says that $x$ takes 1 if it is between $τ_i$ and $τ_{i+1}$, where i goes from 1 to $K+2M-1$.
This confused me, $τ_1$ and $τ_{1+1}$ were both told earlier to take equal values, so how can this $x$ be satisfied to be between $i$ and $i+1$?

$M=4$，Since the order of the cubic spline is equal to 4.